# How to open an MDI parent by clicking on a button in C#?

Tags: c#, mdiparent

I have two forms; `form 1` which contains the button `button1` and `MDIParent form`.

By clicking the `button1` I want to be redirected to the `MDIparent form`.

I am using the following code in click event of the `button1`

```
MDIParent f = new MDIParent();
f.ShowDialog();
```

However, the code gives no response when the button is being clicked.

Comment: you just need to hide the form 1 on click of button1. MDIParent will become visible itself.

Answer (score 0):

**You Must set Parent Form Property (IsMdiContainer = True)**

```
        MDIParent f = new MDIParent();
        f.MdiParent = this;
        f.Show();
```